# How to find TP,TN, FP and FN values from 8x8 Confusion Matrix

Tags: weka, confusion-matrix

I have confusion matrix as follow:

```
   a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h   <-- classified as

 1086    7    1    0    2    4    0    0 |    a

    7 1064    8    6    0    2    2    0 |    b

    0    2 1091    2    3    0    1    1 |    c

    0    8    0 1090    1    1    0    0 |    d

    1    1    1    1  597    2    2    0 |    e

    4    2    1    0    3 1089    0    1 |    f

    0    2    1    3    0    0  219    0 |    g

    0    0    1    0    1    4    1  443 |    h
```

Now how to find the True positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative values from this confusion matrix.
The Weka gave me TP Rate is that same as True positive value ?

Comment: Your distinction between TP Rate and True positive value is unclear to me.  Additionally, it is unclear to me if you simply want to calculate these different values by hand, or if you want Weka to report them.  Finally, are you using the Weka GUI or API?  I think I can help if you clear up some of these questions for me!

Comment: Thanks Walter for your comments. Weka gives me TP rate for each of the class so is that the same value which comes from confusion matrix? that's what I want to know. Second is I want to calculate those values by hand (if Weka give those values i don't mind). I am using Weka GUI for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have total 8 classes: `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`. You will thus get 8 different `TP, FP, FN,` and `TN` numbers. For instance, in the case of `a` class,

```
TP (instance belongs to a, classified as a) = 1086
FP (instance belongs to others, classified as a) = 7 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 4 + 0 + 0 = 12
FN (instance belongs to a, classified as others) = 7 + 1 + 0 + 2 + 4 + 0 + 0 = 14
TN (instance belongs to others, classified as others) = Total instance - (TP + FP + FN)
```

`TP rate` is not `TP`. It is the `Recall` or `TP/TP+FN`.

Comment: one question is that..Is it ok if TN Value comes greater than TP value.? My classifier gives me much better result (Correctly classified instances are 6679 out of 6769), 98.67% . How to justify the same with TP value??

Comment: It depends. If you have more negatives than positives, then having much greater TN does not help. Your accuracy then can get high just because your learner saying everything (almost) as negative. In that case P, R, F are better statistics.

Answer (score 0):

a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h   <-- classified as

1086    7    1    0    2    4    0    0 |    a

```
7 1064    8    6    0    2    2    0 |    b

0    2 1091    2    3    0    1    1 |    c

0    8    0 1090    1    1    0    0 |    d

1    1    1    1  597    2    2    0 |    e

4    2    1    0    3 1089    0    1 |    f

0    2    1    3    0    0  219    0 |    g

0    0    1    0    1    4    1    0 |    h
```

Comment: What makes the result of h become all zero even if the true positive